Distance SOQL for multiple Records
I want to get near locations of multiple related records' location of the parent record to display in a map.
Is it possible to make Distance SOQL for multiple geolocations without putting SOQL into loop?
Second way might be getting all records and comparing their locations which looks impractical and probably hit heap limit as well.
How should I approach this.
Edit: To be more clear, Opportunity will have a map that will displays sub locations related to itself with near locations apart from the current opportunity's locations. Think it as physically located assets that are related to Opportunity, and user wants to see what already established near to these sub locations.
Edit 2: Lookslike the post was so vague. Here is more details of the process. I created an LWC to display some locations in the opportunity object. The locations are stored in different custom object for various reasons but lets call it Address__c. Address object is connected to Opportunity with a junction object for many to many relationships. In the map, User want to see connected locations which are defined through junction. However They also want to see what other locations are near by to these defined locations. Hope this makes it more clear.

What do you mean by "multiple-related locations in the parent record"?  Please [edit] to clarify and describe what the parent and child objects are.

@DavidCheng Done

You will have to either do a SOQL query per "sublocation" or have a SOQL query where each "sublocation" has a measure to every "location" (if I understand your example correctly). I suggest you [edit] the question to make it more concrete, by showing some object names (can be fictional) and what object records you want distances between, and how these objects are related to each other.

@PhilW yep, exactly like that. I added more explanations of the process.

It sounds, to me, like you do need the LWC to do a separate call to an aura enabled method that itself finds "nearby locations" for each given location, as it sounds like you want to use the distance as a WHERE clause constraint.

@PhilW Yea, I decided to do this with async await for the aura method. Thanks

Personally I would consider allowing up to 5 calls at the same time as you will get the results back more quickly, real time. And that means not using await, but rather using a Promise.

Thank you @PhilW for the improvement. I used promise.all with async await.
Here is the code sample:
async getMultipleData(){
    var multiMarkers=[];
    var promiseArray=[];

    for(var i=0; i<this.multicenters.length;i++){

        var singlebatch = getLocation({ 
            centerLatitude: this.multicenters[i].latitude,
            centerLongitude: this.multicenters[i].longitude,
            distanceInKm: this.circleRange
        })
        .then(result => {
            result.forEach(e => {
                multiMarkers.push({lat:e.latitude,lng:e.longitude});
            });
        })
        .catch(error => {console.log('Error fetching data: '+ error);});
        promiseArray.push(singlebatch);
    }
    await Promise.allSettled(promiseArray).then((results) => results.forEach((result) => console.log(result.status)));;

    //map refresh and other stuff
}

